# Recognizing and replacing parts of a string in java 7

Tags: java, string, filter, replace, minecraft

I want to replace a part of a string with another string.  For example, a string comes in, and it contains `meat`, but I want it to change that `meat` to **`vegetable`**.  I know I can do this with the following statement.

`str = str.replaceAll("meat", "vegetable");`

However, I need to have the exact capitalization.  I'm looking for a way to do this no matter what letters are upper or lowercase in the example `meat`.

My application is a filter for Minecraft.  Either swears, or just customizing the menu.  Like I'd like to replace every instance of the word `minecraft`, no matter the capitalization, to say `Best game Ever!!`.

I have modded it so that it can recognize and replace specific capitalizations, but that is very limiting.

I hope I have supplied enough info so that someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make regex case-insensitive by adding `(?i)` flag at start

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)meat", "vegatable");
```

example

```
System.out.println("aBc def".replaceAll("(?i)abc","X")); // out: "X def"
```

Comment: How do I perform on more complex replacements? Like, replace Math.sin(30) with Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(30)) in a complete expression string.

Comment: @SharjithN. You can try to reuse part from capturing group `replaceAll("Math\\.sin\\((\\d+)\\)", "Math.sin(Math.toDegrees($1))")`

Comment: @SharjithN. But if you would like to do some more complex replacement like replace some number with its incremented value you would need to use Matcher class and its `appendReplacement` and `appendTail`. Here you have example http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645633/1393766

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo.  That worked for me.  The regex backreference substitution.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument to `replaceAll` is a regular expression, and you can embed a flag in the expression to make it case-insensitive:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)meat", "vegatable");
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way: Here the flag is not explicitly in the regex, but passed as a separate parameter.

```
String input = "abc MeAt def";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("meat", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
String output = matcher.replaceAll("vegetable");
System.out.println(output);
```