# Replace each occurrence matched by pattern with method called on that string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public String evaluateString(String s){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("someregex");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while(m.find()){
        m.replaceCurrent(methodFoo(m.group()));
    }
}
```

The problem is that there is no replaceCurrent method.  Maybe there is an equivalent I overlooked.  Basically I want to replace each match with the return value of a method called on that match.  Any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Update:

**Since Java 9** we can use [`Matcher#replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) like

```
String result = Pattern.compile("yourRegex")
                       .matcher(yourString)
                       .replaceAll(match -> yourMethod(match.group()));
                                         // ^^^- or generate replacement directly 
                                         // like `match.group().toUpperCase()`
```

---

**Before Java 9**

You may use [`Matcher#appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) and [`Matcher#appendTail`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail-java.lang.StringBuffer-).

`appendReplacement` will do two things:

1. it will add to selected buffer text placed *between* current match and previous match (or start of string for first match),
2. after that, it will also add replacement for current match (which can be based on it).

`appendTail` will add to buffer text placed *after* current match.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("yourRegex");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, yourMethod(m.group()));
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String result = sb.toString();
```