# IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference while replaceFirst

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace first occurence of `String` matching my regex, while iterating those occurences like this:

(this code is very simplified, so don't try to find some bigger sense of it)

```
Matcher tagsMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\{[sdf]\\}").matcher(value);

int i = 0;
while (tagsMatcher.find()) {
    value = value.replaceFirst("\\{[sdf]\\}", "%" + i + "$s");
    i++;
}
```

I'm getting `IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference` while executing `replaceFirst`. Why?

Comment: for every match, it would do the replace. Then what's the need for replaceFirst?

Comment: Based on your code you should probably be using `matcher.appendReplacement` examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645633/1393766 http://stackoverflow.com/a/25081783/1393766

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar symbol.

```
value = value.replaceFirst("\\{[sdf]\\}", "%" + i + "\\$s");
```

Illegal group reference error occurs mainly because of trying to refer a group which really won't exists.

Answer (score 5):

`replacement` part in `replaceFirst(regex,replacement)` can contain references to groups matched by `regex`. To do this it is using

- `$x` syntax where `x` is integer representing group number,
- `${name}` where `name` is name of named group `(?<name>...)`

Because of this ability `$` is treated as special character in `replacement`, so if you want to make `$` literal you need to

- escape it with `\` like `replaceFirst(regex,"\\$whatever")`
- or let `Matcher` escape it for you using `Matcher.quote` method `replaceFirst(regex,Matcher.quote("$whatever"))`

BUT you shouldn't be using

```
value = value.replaceFirst("\\{[sdf]\\}", "%" + i + "\\$s");
```

inside loop because each time you do, you need to traverse entire string to find part you want to replace, so each time you need to start from beginning which is very inefficient.

Regex engine have solution for this inefficiency in form of `matcher.appendReplacement(StringBuffer, replacement)` and `matcher.appendTail(StringBuffer)`.

- `appendReplacement` method is adding to StringBuffer all data until current match, and lets you specify what should be put in place of matched by regex part
- `appendTail` adds part which exists after last matched part

So your code should look more like

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int i = 0;

Matcher tagsMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\{[sdf]\\}").matcher(value);
while (tagsMatcher.find()) {
    tagsMatcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement("%" + (i++) + "$s"));
} 
value = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Special character $ can be handled is simple way. Check below example

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String test ="Other company in $ city ";
        String test2 ="This is test company ";
        try{
            test2= test2.replaceFirst(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("test"),  Matcher.quoteReplacement(test));
            System.out.println(test2);
            test2= test2.replaceAll(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("test"),  Matcher.quoteReplacement(test));
            System.out.println(test2);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
This is Other company in $ city  company 
This is Other company in $ city  company
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using apache commons, `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.replaceOnce`. This is regex safe.