# Does Java have an equivalent to .NET's Regex.Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator)

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a Regex replace method in java similar to [Regex.Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx).  In particular, I need to be able to dynamically specify the replacement string based on what was matched. If there is no direct equivalent, is there an idiomatic approach to doing something similar?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: [Replace each occurrence matched by pattern with method called on that string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645291/replace-each-occurrence-matched-by-pattern-with-method-called-on-that-string)

Comment: use [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Or maybe [`Matcher.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-)